# What is wrong with following C++ code (regarding shared_ptr)

Tags: c++

I am trying to get up to speed with using shared_ptr, but I can't seem to figure out why the following code wont compile.

In the header file, private member declaration:

```
std::map<std::string, str::tr1::shared_ptr< std::vector<int> > > *_myMap;
```

In the constructor, trying to instantiate an object of the above:

```
_myMap = new map<string, std::tr1::shared_ptr< vector<int> > >();
```

The error message:

```
Test.cpp:14:68: error: cannot convert ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::vector<int> > >*’ to ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::vector<int> >*’ in assignment
```

I'd like to convert my pointers step by step, but I can't seem to figure out why the above shoots an error. Can anyone advise? Thanks!

EDIT:

I found out why. I had 2 vim instances open, and one was writing to a temporary swap file and not actually looking at the changes when compiling. Thanks for the input guys.

Comment: What do I have to do to make the code look for formal?

Comment: Post a complete file that demonstrates the problem (with the header copy-pasted into the source file, and with everything not needed to demonstrate the problem removed). The error message looks to me as if you have not declared `_myMap` with the type you say you've declared it with, so that's as far as I personally can get with what you've posted. If that is indeed the problem, then a `typedef` would help avoid such mistakes.

Comment: Why do so good and then, at the last step, have a raw pointer to your map structure? :/ It should either be a value or it too should be in a smart pointer.

Comment: @GMan: let's get one `shared_ptr` working first, though ;-)

Comment: @Steve: Fiiiiine. :) @dustin: If you used typedef's, you'd only need to check of two simple identifiers matched and not a complex composite type.

Comment: @Steve: Seems like he shouldn't be dynamically allocating the vector at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have posted your code verbatim.

Your header must say `std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> > *_myMap;`

Are you sure you're building properly? Try a fresh build.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The original code that I posted is a straight copy-paste of the code from the header. I tried make clean->make, but still the same

Comment: @dustin: That is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that is the current definition? The error says your map is declared in the header as

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> >*
```

Comment: Thats exactly why I'm confused because in the header its declared the same. Very weird...